# one-hot encoded Keras CNN output not as expected

Tags: python, keras, output, conv-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I have a simple problem to solve in which there are 32 filters which are the same size as the image(1x2048). Therefore, the filter's weights will be multiplied  one by one with the pixels rather than convolving over them.

The output for each image is a one-hot-vector, for example [1,0,0,0]. when I sum two images and do the pridiction, the output will be either [1,0,0,0] or [0,0,1,0].

However, since I have summed the two images, I expect to get [1,0,1,0] as the output to understand that I have both both of the classes in the image. Yet, I am don't know what to do to get what I expect and where the problem can be.

```
input_shape=(1,2048,1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(1, 2048), strides=(1, 1),
activation='softmax', 
input_shape=input_shape,
kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1(L1regularization),
kernel_constraint=keras.constraints.non_neg()            ))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,     
optimizer=optimizer,metrics=[metrics])
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of softmax's properties -`softmax` function maximazes high values. Then, there's only one maximum for softmax function in most cases. Softmax:

[image: softmax]

You can get two maximums for the softmax, if input of softmax contains two equal higest values. It is possible in a very rare case when the same values (logits) were produced by convolutional filters. Otherwise, there's only one maximum, then, one class predicted.

Example from [github](https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2017/08/13/softmax-and-the-negative-log-likelihood/): [image]

In a case of the last image, softmax produses two similar values. But you shouldn't expect that all the time.
Check an output of `Conv2D` layer with `linear` activation, if you want to check this assumption.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(1, 2048), strides=(1, 1),
    activation='linear', 
    input_shape=input_shape,
    kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1(L1regularization),
    kernel_constraint=keras.constraints.non_neg()))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

is's the same architecture, but you [get output](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer) of `Conv2D`.

Comment: Yea I understood that the problem is from the Softmax activation that I have used. But what would you perhaps recommend me to do as a solution to have outputs. Thanks.

Comment: @alireSaRanjbar usually tasks are similar to your task solved by multiple binary classifiers, one for each class of image. Is there a reason to avoid this way?